# how to print several products on the same page with odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9

here is the template that I use but the products are printed each on its page whereas I want the product to be printed on a page once the page is full that it continues on a new page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="stock_view_report_template">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                        <div class="page">
                            <h2>Stock actuel</h2>
                            <table class="table table-condensed">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>product</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Location</th>
                                        <th>Owner</th>
                                        <th>Lot</th>
                                        <th>Incoming Date</th>
                                        <th>Inventory Value</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <td><span t-field="o.product_id.name"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-field="o.qty"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-field="o.location_id.name"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-field="o.owner_id"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-field="o.lot_id"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-field="o.in_date"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-field="o.inventory_value"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Just use `<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">` a little later, for example exactly after the `div` with the `page` class.

Comment: By using `loop` in template